# Flex - get label height after setting text property

Tags: apache-flex, layout, flex-spark

I'm looping through a recordset, and for each item I create at runtime a spark Label and set the text property from a field of the recordset. The labels must have a fixed width and some text goes multiline.
I want to arrange the label vertically so I need to know the height of the label so I can place the next label properly, but when I try to read this property, after the labels is added through the addElement method, it returns 0.

Do you know how to get the label height?

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not just using a List Component to display your labels? It sounds like what you describe is available out of the box.

Comment: Ehmmm... actually ...no! You're right! I was addressing this problem with an HTML-like approach instead of reasoning in terms of list and vertical/horizontal container. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [VGroup](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/VGroup.html) or a [List](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff923c946c5112135c8ee9e-7fff.html) for this instead. It will automatically handle this kind of behaviour for you. Make sure to set `variableRowHeight` to true.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works perfectly!!! Now I have only to set some margin around the list, but it works great. Thank you!